# How to calculate percentage of attendance in Google Sheet for a class

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets

How do I calculate the percentage of a student, when a student has been present.

[image]

If you see the google sheet image above, you would pretty much understand what I am asking for.

Need to get the Percentage of attendance of each student in my class. where

- P = Present
- A = Absent
- NA = The class was cancelled for the day

We have our classes only on weekends.

Comment: =COUNTIFS(B2:I2, "P")/(COUNTIFS(B2:I2, "P") + COUNTIFS(B2:I2, "A") )*100

I am able to get the result with this formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
=COUNTIF(C2:I2,"P")/COUNTA(C2:I2)
```

Note: this formula starts at `C2` to ignore the first `NA` week

No need to multiply this formula by 100, just format the cells as *percentage*

---

The formula you offered in the comments (also below) is a perfectly valid solution

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:I2, "P")/(COUNTIFS(B2:I2, "P") + COUNTIFS(B2:I2, "A"))
```